# How to print prompt box output results on a new blank page instead of the alert box itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

- After putting in the number or name in the prompt boxes and clicking submit, I want the outputs to get printed on another page instead of an alert box or using .innerhtml. On Click->User types in their name or their 2 payment numbers it gets added for a total->Results get printed on a separate page with text.

```js
function myName() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your first and last name", " ");
    
    if (person != null) {
        
        alert("Hello " + person + " " + "Welcome to World Travels!!!");
    }
}

function myPayment() {
    var a = Number(prompt("Enter first payment: "));
    var b = Number(prompt("Enter second payment: "));    

    if (a + b != null) {
        window.location.href = 'otherPage.html#a:' + a + ';b:' + b; 
    }
}

function myCheck() {
    alert("Program Number NO: 002462\nReservation NO: A987VBS\nConfirmation N0: 786543\nStatus: Excellent and trip on time.\nHave a nice trip.");
    }
```

```css
h2  {
    background-color:black;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    color:white;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    text-align:center;

    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;


    padding-left:12px; 
 padding-right:12px;
 padding-top:12px;
 padding-bottom:12px;
 
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:yellow;
    }

.boxed {
  color:blue;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-right:50px; 
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  padding-left:15px; 
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-bottom:15px; 
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black;
  }

body    { 
  margin:0;
  background-color:blue;
  }

footer {
  font-size:75%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  }


.scroll-left  {
     height: 50px; 
     overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    
    color: white;
    }

.scroll-left p {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); 
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */ 
 -moz-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
      }

/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll-left {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);   
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}

.greytext  {
    color:gray;
    padding-left:5px;
    }

.buttons {
   text-align:center;
   }

.join_button  {
    
    background-color:yellow;
    }

.payment_button {
   
    background-color:red;
    }

.check_button  {
   
    background-color:#00FFFF;
      }

hr  {
 color:gray;
 }

.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!--File Information -->
<!--Document Name:Midhtml.txt --> 
<!--Author: Andreas Lambadarios  --> 
<!--Date Created: 10/29/16 --> 
<!--Date Updated: 10/29/16 --> 
<!-- Description:   -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->

<html lang="en">
<title>Mid Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project3css.css">
<script src="project3js.js"></script>

</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<h2 id"top_header">The Best of World Travel Programs</h2>

&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<div class="scroll-left">
<p>Welcome To Our Best Program and Price!</p>
</div>


<div class="boxed">
  This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!   This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!   This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!   This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!   This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!   This site you will learn about thousands of travel destinations.  So many wonderous places await you!!!
</div>


<div class="scroll-left">
<p>Don't Wait Limited Time Only!</p>
</div>


<div class="blink_me">
<p class="greytext">Select your choice by clicking one of the following buttons:</p>
</div>

&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp; 


<div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="myName()" class="join_button" type="button">Join</button>
    
    <button onclick="myPayment()" class="payment_button" type="button">Payment</button>
    
    <button onclick="myCheck()" class="check_button" type="button">Check-In</button>
</div>

<hr>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; Andreas Lambadarios 2016</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

- All of the javascript functions work properly.  What I primarily want is the name and payment info to get printed on a separate page.

Comment: The payment prompt function is not computing properly

Comment: I fixed the computation nevermind

Comment: is PHP an option for you??

Comment: I wish PHP was unfortunately I need to utilize javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that after entering the data, the user should get redirected to a page displaying that data?
In that case, you need to use a way to pass variables between those pages: database, cookies, web storage, query string or url fragment (that's what comes into my mind right now).

Let's take for example that last one. What you could try, is:

```
function myPayment() {
    var a = Number(prompt("Enter first number"));
    var b = Number(prompt("Enter second number"));    

    if (a + b != null) {
        window.location.href = 'otherPage.html#a:' + a + ';b:' + b; 
    }
}
```

On `otherPage.html`, you could then include the following script to retrieve those values again:

```
function getPaymentValues() {
    var hashValues = window.location.hash.substring(1).split(';');
    var storedValues = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < hashValues.length; i++) {
        var keyValue = hashValues[i].split(':');
        storedValues[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    }

    return storedValues;
}
```

You could then get the values from the object again just by using the keys specified in the fragment, like `storedValues.a` or `storedValues.b`. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dMvjE2g4EhHNn3dpnpwZ?p=preview) is a Plunker demonstrating this.

Please note that this means though that the user can specify the keys with their values in the url, which might be a security concern to you. I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to do, but you might want to use something server side instead, backed by a database.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: it should look like this when redirected: [link] (https://i.imgur.com/K8Vww7d.png)

Comment: the redirection works but how do I utilize the keys in the fragment properly?

Comment: I've added [a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dMvjE2g4EhHNn3dpnpwZ?p=preview) demonstrating it, @AndreasLambadarios. I'm not sure what you're exactly trying to do, but please note this could pose a security concern, since you're displaying the values the user could edit in the url.

Comment: I fully understand and see that the values of a and b are in the url and can be tweaked by the user.  Security isn't a issue for this simple demo mockup I needed.  Highly appreciate your time and effort for explaining.

Comment: You're welcome @AndreasLambadarios! If it was helpful to you and it solved your problem, please accept my answer. ;)